# Python: how to pass argument name using variable

Tags: python, parameter-passing

A module I'm using has many functions defined with different argument names more or less serving the same purpose:

```
def func1(start_date):
    ....
def func2(startdate):
    ....
def func3(s_date):
    ....
def func4(sdate):
    ....
```

and they appear all in different positions of the argument list (in the above simplified case they're all in position 1, but in reality that's not the case).

I want to write a wrapper that can pass the actual `start_date` to any of these functions via a dictionary from function name to argument name:

```
def func2arg_name():
    return {'func1' : 'start_date', 
            'func2' : 'startdate', 
            'func3' : 's_date', 
            'func4' : 'sdate' }
```

Then the actual wrapper:

```
f2a = func2arg_name()
def func(func_name, sdate):
    locals()[func_name](f2a[func_name] = sdate)

func('func1', '20170101')
```

Clearly this doesn't work. Essentially the f2a[func_name] is not being recognized as a legit keyword. Does any one know how to do this, i.e. pass the argument name using a variable? Note `func1` to `func4` are externally defined and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a dict with the argument name as the key, and pass it using unpack operator:

```
locals()[func_name](**{f2a[func_name]: sdate})
```

See [Unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial.